# is there a way we can make functions that return pointers in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I mean, can we make functions return pointer like in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>      
int* sum(int* ptr_1, int* ptr_2){
    return (*ptr_1 + *ptr_2);   
}       
int main() {
    int x=0, y=0;
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    int *ptr_x = &x;
    int* ptr_y = &y;
    printf("%d", *sum(ptr_x, ptr_y));
    return 0;
}
```

This code takes 2 int numbers and prints sum of them using pointers. It didn't work on ssh but I wanted to ask anyway.

Comment: May I ask why are you returning a pointer to `int` rather than `int`?

Comment: What you are asking for and the title of your question mean very different things.

Comment: A "correct" way to do this would be `malloc` an `int` in `sum`, point that to `*ptr_1 + *ptr_2`, then return that pointer. But that's a roundabout and silly way to sum two `int`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is buggy. It returns the sum of two `int`s as a pointer which doesn't make sense.

You *can* return pointers, but they should also point *at* something (or `NULL`). Dereferencing the pointer returned by `sum` (as you do in the `printf` line) will almost certainly cause undefined behavior.

A contrived but working version of your program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int *sum(int *ptr_1, int *ptr_2) {
    // `static` makes `result` stored between calls so it isn't destroyed
    // when the function returns:
    static int result;
    result = *ptr_1 + *ptr_2;
    return &result;           // return a pointer pointing at result
}

int main() {
    int x, y;
    if(scanf("%d %d", &x, &y) != 2) return 1;

    int *ptr_x = &x;
    int *ptr_y = &y;
    
    printf("%d", *sum(ptr_x, ptr_y));
}
```

Comment: Note that using static variables might not be a solid solution. If you invoke `sum` twice it will return 2 pointers to the same memory. The first dereferenced value is overwritten by the second call. Instead you might want to `malloc(sizeof(int))` then let the caller `free` the pointer.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yes, and I would never really return a pointer for a case like this - but the example stays pretty close to OP:s code to show that it _is_ possible to return a pointer. If I involve `malloc` etc here, it'll probably over shadow that point.

Comment: this explained so much thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, functions can return pointers.

Your problem is that the expression `*ptr_1 + *ptr_2` yields a value of type `int`, not `int *` (each of `*ptr_1` and `*ptr_2` are `int`s, so adding them together gives you an `int` value).

Whatever that integer value is, it's likely *not* a valid pointer (it's not the address of an object during that object's lifetime), and the behavior on dereferencing an invalid pointer is *undefined*.  Your code may crash, you may get nonsensical output, something else may happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can return a pointer, but in this specific case, you do not need to, your `sum` should simply return an int, not a pointer to int:

```
 int sum(int* ptr_1, int* ptr_2){
    return (*ptr_1 + *ptr_2);   
 }
```

Comment: so return &(*ptr_1 + *ptr_2) might work right ?

Comment: @alperortac No, because in that case, the function will returns the reference (address) of a temporary variable, that exists only within the scope of the function, and even only within the scope of that specific arithmetic operation. Its like giving the post address of a camping tent that vanish the day after, postman will found nothing at the given address.